# DATETIME в MySQL вернуть значение без учета timezone

Tags: javascript, mysql, datetime, timezone

TimeZone в БД и на машине +2. В БД хранится DATETIME 2018-11-26 16:00:00.
Когда я достаю эту дату оно возвращает мне ее в формате 2018-11-26T14:00:00.000**Z**.

И когда я сделаю так:

```
new Date("2018-11-26T14:00:00.000Z")
```

оно вернет мне дату 2018-11-26 16:00:00, но если на машине будет +3, то вернет 17:00:00.

А если бы БД вернула дату например такую: 2018-11-26T16:00:00.000, и если ее положить в Date:

```
new Date("2018-11-26T16:00:00.000")
```

то возвращаемое время не зависимо от зоны на машине будет одним и тем же, что и требуется мне. 
Как можно этого достичь?

Comment: date_default_timezone_set('UTC');

Comment: я на PHP не работаю все через js. А в js Date нельзя задать временную зону.

Comment: Преобразование делает ваш ORM или библиотека доступа. `mysql` отвечает именно `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS` форматом без всяких таймзон. Потому что у `DATETIME` таймзоны нет, это не `TIMESTAMP`. fractional part может быть, если вы в определение поля заказали его выдавать.

Comment: @Мелкий согласен с вами DATETIME должен нормально возвращать значение по ману. Думал я что то не понимаю. С ORM и библиотекой все нормально, пойду почитаю про fractional part

Comment: `С ORM и библиотекой все нормально` - не нормально. Коверкают данные именно они. А fractional part - это доли секунды, для `datetime` (не `datetime(N)` они не выводятся.

Comment: @Мелкий Спасибо, вы правы. Проблема в js библиотеке mysql. В конфигурации надо добавить поле `dateStrings: true` по умолчанию стоит false. Напишите свой ответ чтоб я смог отметить, что он правильный.